# Accidentally removed ia32-libs and now GUI is not working

Tags: gui, uninstall

I have removed accidently i32-libs... using the following command

```
sudo apt-get remove ia32-libs
```

Now the GUI is not properly working. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Execute `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop --reinstall` to make sure all required libraries are there and potentially fix it.

Comment: I did that... Does not change anything... It seems that lot of other libraries are missing/...

Answer (score 0):

Check /var/log/dpkg.log what packages have been installed/removed since.
This command may help to figure out what happened:

```
$ grep remove /var/log/dpkg.log
```