# Accedently removed ia32-libs and now gui not working in ubuntu 10.04

Tags: gui, uninstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accidentally removed ia32-libs and now GUI is not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113814/accidentally-removed-ia32-libs-and-now-gui-is-not-working)

I have removed accidently i32-libs. Now the GUI is not properly working. How can I fix it?